# Password Filed Validation not working in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I had multiple images based on the text changes in textfield I need to change the image as selected like when user enter capital letter and small letter and special character and number based on that image get selected ..but I can't change according that.
here is my code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: Any) {

    if isValidated(passwordTextField.text!){

       print("succ")
    }
}

func isValidated(_ password: String) -> Bool {
    var lowerCaseLetter: Bool = false
    var upperCaseLetter: Bool = false
    var digit: Bool = false
    var specialCharacter: Bool = false

    for char in password.unicodeScalars {
        if !lowerCaseLetter {
            lowerCaseLetter = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters.contains(char)

        }
        if !upperCaseLetter {
            upperCaseLetter = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(char)
        }
        if !digit {
            digit = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char)
        }

        if !specialCharacter {
            specialCharacter = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.contains(char)
        }
    }

    if  (specialCharacter) {
        //do what u want
        self.SpecialCharacter_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
        return false
    }
    if  ( digit) {
        //do what u want
        self.onenumberImageCondiotion_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
        return false
    }

    if  ( lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter) {
        //do what u want
        self.UpperCaseImageConditions_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
        return false
    }
    else {
        self.UpperCaseImageConditions_img.image = UIImage(named: "redtick")
        self.SpecialCharacter_img.image = UIImage(named: "redtick")
        self.onenumberImageCondiotion_img.image = UIImage(named: "redtick")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 3? Really? Did we enter a time warp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the isValidated method just needs a little tweaking:

I changed it a little bit and it works in my test project.

```
func isValidated(_ password: String) -> Bool {
    var lowerCaseLetter: Bool = false
    var upperCaseLetter: Bool = false
    var digit: Bool = false
    var specialCharacter: Bool = false

    for char in password.unicodeScalars {
        if !lowerCaseLetter {
            lowerCaseLetter = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters.contains(char)

        }
        if !upperCaseLetter {
            upperCaseLetter = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(char)
        }
        if !digit {
            digit = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char)
        }

        if !specialCharacter {
            specialCharacter = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.contains(char)
        }
    }

    if  (lowerCaseLetter) {
        lowercaseLabel.text = "✅ Has a lowercase letter"
        lowercaseLabel.textColor = .green
        lowercaseLabel.sizeToFit()
    } else {
        lowercaseLabel.text = "Does not have a lowercase letter"
        lowercaseLabel.textColor = .red
        lowercaseLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    if (upperCaseLetter) {
        uppercaseLabel.text = "✅ Has an uppercase letter"
        uppercaseLabel.textColor = .green
        uppercaseLabel.sizeToFit()
    } else {
        uppercaseLabel.text = "Does not have an uppercase letter"
        uppercaseLabel.textColor = .red
        uppercaseLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    if  (specialCharacter) {
        specialLabel.text = "✅ Has a special character"
        specialLabel.textColor = .green
        specialLabel.sizeToFit()
    } else {
        specialLabel.text = "Does not have a special character"
        specialLabel.textColor = .red
        specialLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    if  (digit) {
        numberLabel.text = "✅ Has a number"
        numberLabel.textColor = .green
        numberLabel.sizeToFit()
    } else {
        numberLabel.text = "Does not have a number"
        numberLabel.textColor = .red
        numberLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    if lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter && digit && specialCharacter {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

The last part is important where you have to check that all the conditions are true, or else return false.  Also, I removed the return false code in each of the sections where you put '// do what you want' because I don't think the function should return false except at the final check.

Then in the specific 'if statements' where you check for each subcondition being true, add an else statement that will toggle/set your images for either state (e.g. green tick for true, red X for false).

Project Code:
https://github.com/Wattholm/PasswordValidator

Comment: You may also want to check if CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters is what you want.  It is a not quite an exhaustive set of special characters. These characters for example: ~$^+= are not part of that set.